# DirectSound: setting the volume to a percentage

Tags: c#, directx, directsound

The Volume-Property in the SecondaryBuffer class seems to be strange, because a worth around -4000 is 0%, and 0 is 100%, how can I set the Volume to a precise percentage or get the lowest Volume to do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your percentage is a double between 0 and 1 and named volumePercentage:

```
double adjustedVolume = (1d - volumePercentage) * -4000d;
```